# set unique identifier for RunningTaskInfo

Tags: java, android

I am writing an Android App recently and I create several activities using **FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK** and **FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASKS**.
And I want to get the info of these new tasks(as well as activities)by using **getRunningTasks**.
Also I want to set some unique identifiers for these tasks in order to manage them conveniently.
I have tried to use the **description**, but it can not be modified.Codes are as followed:

```
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfos = am.getRunningTasks(2);
    ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo currentTaskInfo = taskInfos.get(0);
    am.getRunningTasks(2).get(0).description = "dfasdfsa";  
    Toast.makeText(this,am.getRunningTasks(2).get(0).description, 10).show();
```

When the Toast shows, the value of description is still **null**.I seems I can not change it.
Please give me a solution to set a unique identifier for a task.
I really appreciate your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

First, this is not the way to set your taskDescription. To set your taskDescription you need to use this method:

```
ActivityManager.TaskDescription taskDescription = 
            new  ActivityManager.TaskDescription("label");
this.setTaskDescription(taskDescription);
```

This is a simple constructor of TaskDescription, for more constructors, check:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.TaskDescription
You can set more description variables there.

Secondly,
am.getRunningTasks(2).get(0).description this was depricated a while ago, however, some vendors even didn't allow it to be used before that.

To check your description if it is set to your value, for example, you can run

```
adb shell dumpsys activity activities
```

However, if you really want to check it in runtime, it is available after API 21:

```
final ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<ActivityManager.AppTask> appTasks = am.getAppTasks();
for(ActivityManager.AppTask task : appTasks) {
       Log.d("TaskDesc", "taskDesc: " + task.getTaskInfo().taskDescription);
}
```