# How to manage multiple activities with the same name inside an app

Tags: java, android

I am currently writing an Android app to work as an activity launcher.
The main activity works as launcher and will let users launches a new activity from the main activity(here I create this new activity using **FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK** and **FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASKS**).
So that I can hold multiple these activities with the same name but different content in the background.
But I still need a method to manage them, which means I can offer a UI for user to choose to restart one and kill one.
Can someone give me a good solution?
I appreciate your help very much!
And you can also view a similar question asked by me yesterday: [set unique identifier for RunningTaskInfo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25199404/set-unique-identifier-for-runningtaskinfo)

Comment: What do you mean by "the same name"? Do you mean the same **class** name? Or do you mean the same **variable** name? Please show some code that illustrates what you are doing now?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice the same name means the same activity's name for them.These activities share the same acvitity name, and that's why I use **FLAG_ACITIVITY_NEW_TASK** and **FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASKS**.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17486672/list-of-all-of-the-activities-running-on-the-device to see if it can help.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Thanks for your link, but I don't think it will help because I know how get the running task information.I still want to set a unique and stable identifer for these tasks, not just get their information.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the list of `Activity` instances which are running in your application. [List of all of the activities in our application that are running on the device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17486672/list-of-all-of-the-activities-running-on-the-device) gives an answer how to do this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't think it will help.Because it can just help me get all the same activities' name.I can not distinguish them.